# paste command with ascending order of name of the files

Tags: unix, paste

I have a folder with files,

ls

```
atom0
atom10
atom11
atom12
.
.
atom19
atom1
atom20
atom21
atom2
....
.....
```

Each file has two columns. I want two combine all files column wise in ascending order of name files, ie

```
paste atom0 atom1 atom2 atom3 ...atom8 atom9 atom10 atom11 atom12.....atom20....> data
```

paste atom* > data

gives data but the order is default order of ls command. ie

```
atom0 atom1 atom11 atom12 . .atom19 atom1 atom20 atom21 atom2 ....
```

How to change this order to ascending order for paste command?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As per [Jonathan Leffler](https://stackoverflow.com/users/15168/jonathan-leffler)'s comment `ls -v` would be the simplest if it is supported.

If your `ls` supports `-v` option.

```
ls -v atom* | xargs paste > data
```

If not, sort could be used.

```
find . -name 'atom*' | sort -n -k1.7 | xargs paste > data
```

The 7 arises from ./atomNNNN, so skipping the leading 6 characters. If you have a different prefix (instead of "atom") update the -k1.7 to reflect it.

Without sort

```
$ find . -name 'atom*'
./atom
./atom0
./atom1
./atom10
./atom11
./atom12
./atom3
./atom9
```

With sort

```
$ find . -name 'atom*' | sort -n -k1.7
./atom0
./atom1
./atom3
./atom9
./atom10
./atom11
./atom12
```

Comment: Also, GNU `ls -v` would list the files in the correct order.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler Ah yes, that is so much simpler. Added. You should post your own answer or I would keep stealing your ideas :)

Comment: You may use them - if I wanted to answer, I would.